# Dynamically displaying components basing on components Input

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'm using an Angular icons library, which can be used in code like that:

```
<library-name-icon-name></library-name-icon-name>
<library-name-grid></library-name-grid>
<library-name-arrow></library-name-arrow>
```

And I have created a `button` component, which should display icons dynamically, basing on its `Input` property, which is e.g. `'grid'` for `<library-name-grid></library-name-grid>`. It works in the same way for every other icon component, so there is a pattern `<library-name + icon name` which I'd like to use in template of this component.

Problem is that I can't find any short way to do that, I don't want to use plenty of `ngIf`, I want to use that names in more dynamic way. Is it possible to create such a solution?

Comment: What is the name of the icon library?

Comment: You can check this official docs https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this for example by simple using [ngSwitch] instead of *ngIf, but if you have a lot of icons and you do not want to write switch cases, and also, pattern is always the same, you can do something like:

Set some reference on all icons

```
<library-name-icon-name #icon></library-name-icon-name>
<library-name-grid #icon></library-name-grid>
<library-name-arrow #icon></library-name-arrow>
```

Then access it using @ViewChildren('icon', { read: ElementRef }) icons: QueryList;

Then iterate through the list of icons, there you can get nativeElement for each icon and for example get element's TAG name, and from the pattern "library-name-" + valueFrom@Input find an appropriate one to show/hide...

You can also make a directive that will get, as an input, your component's @Input property, set directive to each your icon component, and then do the same thing with showing/hiding (in that case you will not have to iterate through the list)

(This is an example if you need to use direct DOM access, but maybe that library can be used in more effective way, but i do not know which library are you using)